# how to save array alues with custom url laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My controller

```
   if ($request->hasFile('slider_image')) {
            foreach($request->file('slider_image') as $slider_image)
            {
            $filenameWithExt = $slider_image->getClientOriginalName ();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $slider_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'. time().'.'.$extension;
            $slider_image->storeAs('public/artists/products/slider_image', $fileNameToStore);
            $data[] = $fileNameToStore;
           
            }
            $fileNameToStoreImg=json_encode($data);
            $input['slider_image'] = $fileNameToStoreImg;

            foreach($fileNameToStoreImg as $index => $fileNameToStoreImgUrl) {

              $input['slider_image_url']=url('storage/artists/products/slider_image/'.$fileNameToStoreImgUrl);

            }
           
         }
```

I want to save this

```
[
    " http: / / 127.0.0.1: 8000 / storage / artists / products / slider_image/artist2_1656578371.jpg",
    "http: / / 127.0.0.1: 8000 / storage / artists / products / slider_image/artist3_1656578371.jpg"
],
```

But it shows

```
  http: / / 127.0.0.1: 8000 / storage / artists / products / slider_image / [ "artist2_1656578371.jpg",
    "artist3_1656578371.jpg" ],
```

Here  am trying save multiple image in array.and some custom URL add to save data how?
Here  am trying save multiple image in array.and some custom URL add to save data how?

Answer (score 0):

What if you did this:

```
   if ($request->hasFile('slider_image')) {
        $data['slider_image'] = [];
        $data['slider_image_url'] = [];
        foreach($request->file('slider_image') as $slider_image)
        {
        $filenameWithExt = $slider_image->getClientOriginalName ();
        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $slider_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'. time().'.'.$extension;
        $slider_image->storeAs('public/artists/products/slider_image', $fileNameToStore);
        array_push($data['slider_image'], $fileNameToStore);
        array_push($data['slider_image_url'], url('storage/artists/products/slider_image/'.$fileNameToStoreImgUrl));
     }
       dd($data); // see if this solves your problem
     }
```

On $data['slider_image'] you'll have an array of file names, on $data['slider_image_url'] you'll have an array of URLs.